# Looking for a manhwa where the main character refuses to give up powers

Tags: story-identification, manga

I saw once on a YouTube short. The main character had just defeated the main boss and the goddess was about to reincarnate him and take away his abilities as well but the main character refuses.

Comment: Do you have a link to that youtube short?

Comment: No, it was from a while back and I can’t find it.

Answer (score 1):

After major digging, I found it. I was thinking of ***[Bizarre Restaurant](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/bizarre-restaurant)***.

> The era of Stinky tofu, Durian, Surströmming is over. Have you heard about the cooking so bad that you could die on the spot! But your skill would be increasing!? Endure it! If you eat it and don’t die, your level will go up! And then on behalf of me, protect the earth! ‘Bizarre Restaurant’ is open even when the world is going to end.